# Check if number is a power of two

Tags: haskell, bit-manipulation

I want to check whether or not a number is a power of two in Haskell.
So far I have the following:

```
import Data.Bits

checkPowerTwo :: Int -> Bool
checkPowerTwo num =
        ((.&.) num (num-1)) == 0
```

However, as I just found out, part of the assignment was to do this **without** using imports. Any pointers or examples on how to do that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you’re a ways into learning Haskell, you’ve probably solved a few problems with recursion by this point. Can you think of a way to define powers of two recursively, starting from a small base? Alternatively, how would you look at a number and determine if it was a power of two manually? (Hint: division and remainder are available in the `Prelude`, i.e. without imports, as `div` and `rem`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can work with a function that is defined recursively:

1. 1 is a power of two; and
2. *n* is a power of two if *n* is greater than one, *n* is even, and *n/2* is a power of two.

You thus can implement this as:

```
checkPowerTwo :: Int -> Bool
checkPowerTwo 1 = True
checkPowerTwo n = …
```